# How to measure vector potential such as that of magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, potential

If we want to measure gravitational potential energy of a body-earth system, we can simply do it by measuring the body's height from ground.

How could we can measure vector potential such as that of magnetic field?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't really measuring the gravitational potential by measuring the height above the ground. You're measuring $r$ and assuming that the equation $V = -GM/r$ describes the potential. There is no way to measure the gravitational potential at some fixed point. The best we can do is measure the change in potential by integrating the gravitational force with respect to distance, that is using the equation:

$$ F = \nabla V $$

So we measure the force $F$ and determine the potential $V$ indirectly.

In a similar way we can't measure the magnetic vector potential $A$ directly, but we can measure the magnetic field $B$ and we know that the $A$ is related to $B$ by:

$$ B = \nabla \times A $$

So we measure the field $B$ and determine the vector potential $A$ indirectly.

Note that the vector potential has a gauge invariance. We can add any zero curl terms to it without changing $B$. Actually there is a similar gauge invariance in the gravitational potential because we can add any constant term to it without affecting the gravitational force $F$. In both cases we can't measure the absolute value of the potential because no such quantity exists. We can only measure its value relative to some chosen reference point.

Comment: This won't take Aharonov-Bohm effect into account, it seems.

Comment: @Ruslan: No, my answer assumes a purely classical description.

Comment: Even taking into account the A-B effect the point value of the vector potential is not observable. The A-B effect is not a statement about broken gauge invariance but really just that on domains with non-trivial topology gauge fields can have topological invariants associates with them.

Answer (score 1):

Not every physical quantity/property is directly measurable as a mark on some instrument but that does not take away anything from their "reality". There is no "internal energy" meter, still we are fairly confident that internal energy is at least as meaningful physical quantity as anything else. Going one step further, we can measure temperature and work but there is no "entropy meter", either. And unless the 3rd axiom is invoked, namely $S \rightarrow 0$ if $T\rightarrow 0$, we can only assign entropy differences to thermodynamic processes. Similarly, with the 1st law we can only get internal energy differences by $calculation$, not an absolute level of internal energy. So, these behave very similarly to the electric potential.

Now if you know the spatial distribution of charges and currents by $measurement$ then you can calculate the scalar and vector potentials just as well as you can calculate internal energy and entropy. Entropy is an integral of the heat capacity, the vector potential is an integral of the current density. For example, in the so-called Lorentz gauge with $t_r = t-\frac{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}{c}$

$$    \mathbf A (\mathbf r , t) = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_\Omega \frac{\mathbf J (\mathbf r' , t_r)}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}\, \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf r'\,$$ and

$$    \phi (\mathbf r , t) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int_\Omega \frac{\rho (\mathbf r' , t_r)}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|}\, \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf r' $$

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to measure the vector potential (A) in the absence of its magnetic field, but a huge solenoid contains most of a very strong magnetic field, with a very strong A, perpendicular to B (thus measurable outside of the solenoid using a nearby laser, that is modulated by A, without B, and corrected for (much weaker) stray fields the solenoid emits).

Answer (score 0):

$\Phi_B=\int\int\vec{B}\cdot \hat{n} dA=\int \int \nabla \times \vec{A}\cdot \hat{n} dA = \int \vec{A}\cdot \hat{dl}$, since $\vec{B}=\nabla \times \vec{A}$ then using Stoke's Theorem.

From this, I think you can estimate $\vec{A}$ by finding the magnetic flux through a small, thin, disk-like region of space and then divide by its circumference. This will only give you the component normal to the surface.

As mentioned elsewhere, there isn't an absolute value you can associate with $\vec{A}$. For example, the flux integrals remain unchanged if instead you use $\vec{A'}=\vec{A}+\nabla f$ for an arbitrary differentiable scalar function $f$.